# Android Room not Compiling in Compose

Tags: android, gradle, android-room

I have recently created a Compose Application in Android Studio Flamingo and have added the room dependencies.

While compiling i get this error:

> gradle assembleDebug --no-daemon

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
      > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 20

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 36s
13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

Then after reading many posts I ran:

> gradle assembleDebug --no-daemon --stacktrace

```
       ---  very long output ---
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 20
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget$Companion.fromTarget(JvmTarget.kt:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain$wireJvmTargetToToolchain$1$1.invoke(DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain.kt:78)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain$wireJvmTargetToToolchain$1$1.invoke(DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain.kt:70)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain$sam$org_gradle_api_Transformer$0.transform(DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain.kt)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ValueSupplier$Present.transform(ValueSupplier.java:541)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.mapValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:82)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.withFinalValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:164)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:245)
        ... 110 more
```

And right now I have no clue how to solve this.
Things I did:

- cross check the `@Query` SQL statements (No problems)
- Checked if all the annotations are done correctly
- Change AS settings to use jvm 20 and 1.9.0 kotlin

This is my `app/build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "<hidden>"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "<hidden>"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 // Tried VERSION_20 but no chnages
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 // "      "          "     "
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8" // Tried 20 but Showed unknown jvmTarget  here
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    val navigation_version = "2.6.0"
    val room_version = "2.5.2"

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigation_version")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

And my root `/build.gradle.kts` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}
```

HOW TO SOLVE THIS???

Answer (score 0):

Why did you tried version 20?

try this config:

```
android {
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdk = 34
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {
    //room
    val roomVersion = "2.5.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

}
```